# Using popBackStack() in Android does not update android-listview with Firebase data

Tags: android, android-listview, firebase

At the beginning of the chat app user see a list off groups (listview group) available and the user have the possibility to create a new group or click on some off the available groups and then start to write messages (listview messages). The functions CreateNewMessage and CreateNewGroup pushes information to firebase correctly 
Above scenarios works finne problems arise when user navigates backwards (popBackStack()) from listview with messages to GroupFragment, here should user be presented a list off available groups but the listview is empty. The ReadGroupData() function is not reading the already created groups from firebase and inserts them in the group listview. How to make this happen?

GroupFragment:

```
  public void ReadGroupData() {
    Firebase  firebaserootRef = new Firebase("https://000.firebaseio.com");
    firebaserootRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot snapshot, String s) {
            if (snapshot.getValue() != null) {
                Group newGroup = new     Group((String)snapshot.child("name").getValue(),             
                (String) snapshot.child("id").getValue());

                if(!groupKeyValues.contains(newGroup.GetId())) {
                    groupKeyValues.add(newGroup.GetId());

                    AddToLstViewGroup(newGroup);
                    System.out.println("Read group data from firebase and 
                    inserted in listView");
                }
            }
        }
    });
}

 public void AddToLstViewGroup(Group newGroup) {
    groupNameList.add(newGroup);

    if(groupAdapter == null) {
        groupAdapter = new GroupAdapter(getActivity(), groupNameList);
    }

    if (lstViewGroup == null) {
        lstViewGroup = (ListView)  getView().
        findViewById(R.id.listView_group);
    }

    lstViewGroup.setOnItemClickListener(onItemClickListener);
    lstViewGroup.setOnItemLongClickListener(onItemLongClickListener);

    groupAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    lstViewGroup.setAdapter(groupAdapter);
}
```

ChatFragment:

```
      public void ReadChatMessages(Firebase firebaseRootRef) {
      firebaseRootRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot snapshot, String s) {
            if (snapshot.child(GetGroupId()).child("messages").
                getChildren() != null) {
                for (DataSnapshot c :

             snapshot.child(GetGroupId()).child("messages").getChildren()) {
                    String key = c.getKey();

                    Message newMessage = new Message();
                    newMessage.SetFrom((String) c.child("from").getValue());
                    newMessage.SetMsg((String)    

                    c.child("message").getValue());
                    newMessage.SetTime((String) c.child("time").getValue());
                    newMessage.SetId((String) c.child("id").getValue());

                    if ((!msgKeyValues.contains(key)) ||     
                      newMessage.GetFrom() != "") {
                        msgKeyValues.add(key);

                        AddToLstViewChat(newMessage);

                        //Automatic scrolls to last line in listView.
                        lstViewChat.setSelection(chatAdapter.getCount() -1);
                   }
                }
            }
        }

    public void AddToLstViewChat(Message newMessage) {
    chatMsgList.add(newMessage);

    if (chatAdapter == null) {
        chatAdapter = new ChatAdapter(getActivity(), chatMsgList);
    }

    if(IsMsgFromMe(newMessage)) {
        lstViewChat = (ListView) 

    getView().findViewById(R.id.listView_chat_message_me);
    } else {
        lstViewChat =  

     (ListView)getView().findViewById(R.id.listView_chat_message_others);
    }

    chatAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    lstViewChat.setAdapter(chatAdapter);
}
```

ChatActivity:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
        getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
    } else {
        finish();
    }
}
```

For all the code click on the link: "http://pastebin.com/97nR68Rm"

SOLUTION!

Kato thank you for you patience and help. I have now found a solution for the problem. I'm calling ReadGroupData() and ReadChatMessages() at the end (before return) in my onCreateView methods. As Kato pointed out onCreate() is not getting called on popBackStack()
 In my AddToLStViewGroup the if statement for lstViewGroup is deleted so now it always sets the listView otherwise it will throw an exception for not finding the correct view,  To clarifying:

Deleted this line:

```
if (lstViewGroup == null) {
       lstViewGroup = (ListView)getView().findViewById(R.id.listView_group);         
}
```

And replaced with:

```
ListView lstViewGroup=(ListView)getView().findViewById(R.id.listView_group);
```

Comment: Can you narrow the scope here? Which part of this is the question? The context given here seems to say: Here is an app I need help debugging, when I'm sure that isn't the intent. Pick exactly one question, and also check out [creating an mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I preciate your respond and feedback i have updated the question at issue. I hope i narrowit down enough, let me know if it still is unclear.

Comment: Looking better. But "are not updating correctly" does not accurately describe the problem. Keep in mind that we don't have the context--we've never seen your app, nor anything other than what you post here--so all we see is a code snippet that is "not updating correctly" and don't really know what that means.

Comment: improved explanation.

Comment: One of our Android engineers suggested that this is "likely an issue with popBackstack calling onCreateView but not onCreate. groupKeyValues will never be cleared, so the listener will never add any groups because every group is already in groupKeyValues."

Comment: Added solution to the question.

Comment: Glad you sorted this. Post your solution as an answer to the question and accept it (after a short wait). It will be helpful to others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kato thank you for you patience and help. I have now found a solution for the problem. I'm calling `ReadGroupData()` and `ReadChatMessages()` at the end (before return) in my onCreateView methods. As Kato pointed out `onCreate()` is not getting called on `popBackStack()`
 In my `AddToLStViewGroup` the `if` statement for `listViewGroup` is deleted so now it always sets the listView otherwise it will throw an exception for not finding the correct view.

To clarify:

I deleted this line:

```
if (lstViewGroup == null) {
       lstViewGroup = (ListView)getView().findViewById(R.id.listView_group);         
}
```

And replaced it with:

```
ListView lstViewGroup =(ListView)getView().findViewById(R.id.listView_group);
```

(The original asker posted the answer as part of the question. I'm copying it here as a matter of housekeeping.)